# Can I speed up this basic linear algebra code?

Tags: python, performance, math, numpy

I was wondering whether it is possible to optimise the following using `Numpy` or mathematical trickery.

```
def f1(g, b, dt, t1, t2):
  p = np.copy(g)
  for i in range(dt):
    p += t1*np.tanh(np.dot(p, b)) + t2*p
  return p
```

where `g` is a vector of length `n`, `b` is an `n`x`n` matrix, `dt` is the number of iterations, and `t1` and `t2`are scalars.

I have quickly ran out of ideas on how to optimise this further, because `p` is used within the loop, in all three terms of the equation: when added to itself; in the dot product; and in a scalar multiplication.

But maybe there is a different way to represent this function or there are other tricks to improve its efficiency. If possible, I would prefer not to use `Cython` etc., but I'd be willing to use it if the speed improvements are significant. Thanks in advance, and apologies if the question is out of scope somehow.

### Update:

The answers provided so far are more focused on what the values of the input/output could be to avoid unnecessary operations. I have now updated the MWE with proper initialisation values for the variables (I didn't expect the optimisation ideas to come from that side -- apologies). `g` will be in the range `[-1, 1]` and `b` will be in the range `[-infinity, infinity]`. Approximating the output is not an option because the returned vectors are later given to an evaluation function -- approximation may return the same vector for fairly similar input, so it is not an option.

---

### MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

iterations = 10000

setup = """
import numpy as np
n  = 100
g  = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n,)) # Updated.
b  = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (n,n)) # Updated.
dt = 10
t1 = 1
t2 = 1/2

def f1(g, b, dt, t1, t2):
  p = np.copy(g)
  for i in range(dt):
    p += t1*np.tanh(np.dot(p, b)) + t2*p
  return p
"""

functions = [
  """
    p = f1(g, b, dt, t1, t2)
  """
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for function in functions:
    print(function)
    print('Time = {}'.format(timeit.timeit(function, setup=setup,
                                           number=iterations)))
```

Comment: do you mean a vector of length n instead of `n-dimensional vector`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Yes, apologies. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: Excellently-phrased question!  However, that's going to be a tough one to speed up... This is the sort of thing `numba.jit` (http://numba.pydata.org/) should be a good fit for (Cython as well). However, that's a heavy dependency to add, and you did say that you'd rather stick to "straight" numpy, if possible.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks. I remember experimenting with `Cython` on this particular piece of code about a month ago, but the speed improvements were negligible. I guess that was because (a) I'm new to `Cython`; and (b) I kept most of everything the same instead of, for example, using `C` loops in place of the dot product. I would be very happy to switch to `Cython` if it can improve performance significantly. Having a look at `numba.jit` now -- thanks! `:-)`

Comment: @sudosensei be a little careful with integer division if you are using python 2.7. Current `t2=0`

Comment: @JoshAdel Thanks, Josh. I was aware of that -- I'm using `Python 3.x`.

Comment: If the number of iterations is only 10 cython/numba will not help you that much. Without mathematical tricks the largest contribution to the overall speed will be the efficiency of the `DGEMM` call. Are you currently using an optimized BLAS with numpy? This is of course assuming you will be using matrices larger then the ones you describe as this only takes 250us per call as shown.

Comment: @Ophion When I ran my tests with `Cython`, I used more than 1000 iterations, but I did not see any significant improvements -- however, I attribute that to my lack of `Cython` knowledge, not to a lack of potential. Also, yes, I am using optimised BLAS with `Numpy`. The number of iterations and length of the matrices will generally be less than 1000, but this function is called more than a million times. Reducing its execution time even only by 10% would be a significant improvement.

Comment: I may be running your sample program incorrectly, but it looks like the terms in the dot product `np.dot(p,b)` are large which makes them very close to one when evaluated in `np.tanh`.

Answer (score 4):

To get the code running much faster without `cython` or `jit` will be very hard, some mathematical trickery may be more the easier approach. It appears to me that if we define a `k(g, b) = f1(g, b, n+1, t1, t2)/f1(g, b, n, t1, t2)` for `n` in positive N, the `k` function should have a limit of `t1+t2` (don't have a solid proof yet, just a gut feeling; it may be a special case for E(g)=0 & E(p)=0 also.). For `t1=1` and `t2=0.5`, `k()` appears to approach the limit fairly quickly, for `N>100`, it is almost a constant of `1.5`.

So I think a numerical approximation approach should be the easiest one.[image]

```
In [81]:

t2=0.5
data=[f1(g, b, i+2, t1, t2)/f1(g, b, i+1, t1, t2) for i in range(1000)]
In [82]:

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(data[0], '.-', label='1')
plt.plot(data[4], '.-', label='5')
plt.plot(data[9], '.-', label='10')
plt.plot(data[49], '.-', label='50')
plt.plot(data[99], '.-', label='100')
plt.plot(data[999], '.-', label='1000')
plt.xlim(xmax=120)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('limit.png')

In [83]:

data[999]
Out[83]:
array([ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,
        1.5])
```

Comment: This supports my answer as well, in that the functional relation is essentially a linear recurrence. It is worth nothing however, that OP states that the number of iterations is on order of 10, thus the limit of large N may not be valid (though in this case it will be).

Comment: +1! Nice idea! But see my updated post for what the expected input is. Apologies for the confusion -- I just did not expect the optimisation ideas to come in the form of input/output values and approximation. You are right: the output will saturate, but the values are not always large enough for that to happen -- in fact, the input starts with very small magnitudes that are generally increased with every call of the function.

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to give this as an answer, as I think it may be an artifact of the input data you gave us. Nevertheless, note that `tanh(x) ~ 1` for for `x>>1`. Your input data, at all times I've run it has `x = np.dot(p,b) >> 1`, hence we can replace the `f1` with `f2`.

```
def f1(g, b, dt, t1, t2):
  p = np.copy(g)
  for i in range(dt):
      p += t1*np.tanh(np.dot(p, b)) + t2*p
  return p

def f2(g, b, dt, t1, t2):
  p = np.copy(g)
  for i in range(dt):
      p += t1 + t2*p
  return p

print np.allclose(f1(g,b,dt,t1,t2), f2(g,b,dt,t1,t2))
```

Which indeed shows the two functions are numerically equivalent. Note that f2 is a [non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Recurrence_Sequence#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations), and can be solved in one step if you choose to do so.

Comment: +1! Thanks. But unfortunately, the tanh of the dot product is not necessarily approximately one. See my updated post for what the expected input is, and why approximation is not a viable option in my case. Apologies for the confusion.